# Calculating a Moving Average MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Good Day,

I am using the following code to calculate the 9 Day Moving average.

```
SELECT SUM(close)
FROM tbl
WHERE date <= '2002-07-05'
AND name_id = 2
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 9
```

But it does not work because it first calculates all of the returned fields before the limit is called. In other words it will calculate all the closes before or equal to that date, and not just the last 9.

So I need to calculate the SUM from the returned select, rather than calculate it straight.

IE. Select the SUM from the SELECT...

Now how would I go about doing this and is it very costly or is there a better way?

Comment: How does this average 'move'?

Comment: It is just a static average calculation now. The moving part is that it is calculated everyday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like

```
SELECT 
  sum(close) as sum,
  avg(close) as average
FROM (
    SELECT 
      (close)
    FROM 
      tbl
    WHERE 
      date <= '2002-07-05'
      AND name_id = 2
    ORDER BY 
      date DESC
    LIMIT 9 ) temp
```

The inner query returns all filtered rows in `desc` order, and then you `avg`, `sum` up those rows returned.

The reason why the `query` given by you doesn't work is due to the fact that the `sum` is calculated first and the `LIMIT` clause is applied after the `sum` has already been calculated, giving you the `sum` of all the rows present

Comment: . . This returns one value.  A moving average is refers to a separate value for each date for "n" records.

Comment: Yes, I assumed the OP wanted the moving avg for a particular day, `2002-07-05`

Comment: this solution works if a particular name_id is provided, is there a way to get the moving average for each name_id in the table?

So means the output will be a table of moving averages for each name_id

Comment: You can remove the filter for `name_id` and add this field within the group by claused, you'd also need to remove the `limit` clause and add the date condition range for 9 days as `date between your_start_date and your_end_date`

Answer (score 27):

If you want the moving average for each date, then try this:

```
SELECT date, SUM(close),
       (select avg(close) from tbl t2 where t2.name_id = t.name_id and datediff(t2.date, t.date) <= 9
       ) as mvgAvg
FROM tbl t
WHERE date <= '2002-07-05' and
      name_id = 2
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
```

It uses a correlated subquery to calculate the average of 9 values.

Comment: Even better. I'm using this on a daily trigger so I just need the MA for a particular day because I am saving the 9 day moving average in the database just for speed. But with this I can potentially let users set their own period for the moving average, downside is speed. Thanks.

Comment: @surfer100 Odd then that this isn't the accepted answer

Comment: Bumping this old thread, because I'm looking for the same answer using epoch timestamps. The issue here is that this doesn't account for weekends.

Comment: @fractal5 You can cast a timestamp to a DATE. To account for missing dates you need to join to a table that contains all the dates (pre-generated).

Comment: I think the datediff() has to be `between 0 and 9`, otherwise also negative datediff()s are counted.

Answer (score 13):

Starting from MySQL 8, you should use window functions for this. Using the window `RANGE` clause, you can create a [logical window](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/10/31/a-little-known-sql-feature-use-logical-windowing-to-aggregate-sliding-ranges/) over an interval, which is very powerful. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  date,
  close,
  AVG (close) OVER (ORDER BY date DESC RANGE INTERVAL 9 DAY PRECEDING)
FROM tbl
WHERE date <= DATE '2002-07-05'
AND name_id = 2
ORDER BY date DESC
```

For example:

```sql
WITH t (date, `close`) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-03', 54 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-05', 51 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-12', 49 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-13', 59 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-15', 30 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-17', 35 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-18', 39 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-19', 47 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-26', 50
)
SELECT
  date,
  `close`,
  COUNT(*) OVER w AS c,
  SUM(`close`) OVER w AS s,
  AVG(`close`) OVER w AS a
FROM t
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY date DESC RANGE INTERVAL 9 DAY PRECEDING)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Leading to:

```
date      |close|c|s  |a      |
----------|-----|-|---|-------|
2020-01-26|   50|1| 50|50.0000|
2020-01-19|   47|2| 97|48.5000|
2020-01-18|   39|3|136|45.3333|
2020-01-17|   35|4|171|42.7500|
2020-01-15|   30|4|151|37.7500|
2020-01-13|   59|5|210|42.0000|
2020-01-12|   49|6|259|43.1667|
2020-01-05|   51|3|159|53.0000|
2020-01-03|   54|3|154|51.3333|
2020-01-01|   50|3|155|51.6667|
```

Comment: Yes, it is nice that MySQL supports windowed functions. I like the window chaining with moving average: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p9QAcJT7U24xHysqKCHFyQ/0

Answer (score 1):

an other technique is to do a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tinyint_asc` (
 `value` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (value)
) ;
​
INSERT INTO `tinyint_asc` VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36),(37),(38),(39),(40),(41),(42),(43),(44),(45),(46),(47),(48),(49),(50),(51),(52),(53),(54),(55),(56),(57),(58),(59),(60),(61),(62),(63),(64),(65),(66),(67),(68),(69),(70),(71),(72),(73),(74),(75),(76),(77),(78),(79),(80),(81),(82),(83),(84),(85),(86),(87),(88),(89),(90),(91),(92),(93),(94),(95),(96),(97),(98),(99),(100),(101),(102),(103),(104),(105),(106),(107),(108),(109),(110),(111),(112),(113),(114),(115),(116),(117),(118),(119),(120),(121),(122),(123),(124),(125),(126),(127),(128),(129),(130),(131),(132),(133),(134),(135),(136),(137),(138),(139),(140),(141),(142),(143),(144),(145),(146),(147),(148),(149),(150),(151),(152),(153),(154),(155),(156),(157),(158),(159),(160),(161),(162),(163),(164),(165),(166),(167),(168),(169),(170),(171),(172),(173),(174),(175),(176),(177),(178),(179),(180),(181),(182),(183),(184),(185),(186),(187),(188),(189),(190),(191),(192),(193),(194),(195),(196),(197),(198),(199),(200),(201),(202),(203),(204),(205),(206),(207),(208),(209),(210),(211),(212),(213),(214),(215),(216),(217),(218),(219),(220),(221),(222),(223),(224),(225),(226),(227),(228),(229),(230),(231),(232),(233),(234),(235),(236),(237),(238),(239),(240),(241),(242),(243),(244),(245),(246),(247),(248),(249),(250),(251),(252),(253),(254),(255);
```

After you can used it like that:

```
select 
    date_add(tbl.date, interval tinyint_asc.value day) as mydate, 
    count(*),
    sum(myvalue)
from tbl inner 
    join tinyint_asc.value <= 30 -- for a 30 day moving average
where date( date_add(o.created_at, interval tinyint_asc.value day ) ) between '2016-01-01' and current_date()
    group by mydate
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is fast:

```
select date, name_id,
case @i when name_id then @i:=name_id else (@i:=name_id)
and (@n:=0)
and (@a0:=0) and (@a1:=0) and (@a2:=0) and (@a3:=0) and (@a4:=0) and (@a5:=0) and (@a6:=0) and (@a7:=0) and (@a8:=0)
end as a,
case @n when 9 then @n:=9 else @n:=@n+1 end as n,
@a0:=@a1,@a1:=@a2,@a2:=@a3,@a3:=@a4,@a4:=@a5,@a5:=@a6,@a6:=@a7,@a7:=@a8,@a8:=close,
(@a0+@a1+@a2+@a3+@a4+@a5+@a6+@a7+@a8)/@n as av
from tbl,
(select @i:=0, @n:=0,
        @a0:=0, @a1:=0, @a2:=0, @a3:=0, @a4:=0, @a5:=0, @a6:=0, @a7:=0, @a8:=0) a
where name_id=2
order by name_id, date
```

If you need an average over 50 or 100 values, it's tedious to write, but 
worth the effort. The speed is close to the ordered select.

Answer (score 0):

Moving MEDIAN (if someone will need it)

```
SELECT date,
   (SELECT AVG(close) AS median
    FROM
        (SELECT close, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY close) AS r,
            COUNT(close) OVER() AS c
        FROM tbl
        WHERE datediff(t.date, date) 
                BETWEEN 1 AND 9
        ) AS t2

    WHERE t2.r BETWEEN FLOOR(t2.c/2)+MOD(t2.c,2) 
                    AND FLOOR(t2.c/2)+1
   ) AS mvgMedian
FROM tbl t
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```