# Moving Average in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql and have a data in the following format:

```
Date       | Product | Value
-----------------------------
2016-01-01 | ProA    | 121.30
2016-01-02 | ProA    | 122.50
2016-01-03 | ProA    | 120.75
2016-01-06 | ProA    | 125.33
2016-01-10 | ProA    | 119.85
-----------------------------
```

My requirement is a query to get an output in the format with the all columns of the above table along with the moving average for 'n' days. It has to query from a big data. The output could be in the following format if the 'n' is 3:

```
Date       | Product | Value  | MovingAvg
-----------------------------------------
2016-01-01 | ProA    | 121.30 | 
2016-01-02 | ProA    | 122.50 | 
2016-01-03 | ProA    | 120.75 | 121.52
2016-01-06 | ProA    | 125.33 | 122.86
2016-01-10 | ProA    | 119.85 | 121.98
-----------------------------------------
```

This query is for using in my applicaion in VB.net
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Is the moving avg correct? Please double-check the expected output

Comment: @ 1000111 the output is correct, the first one 121.52 is the avg of 121.30,122.50, 120.75 and so on for others also

Comment: Would you please explain the output? Aren't you calculating **Cumulative moving average**?

Comment: @Kris you just changed the output, what is correct now? 123.04 doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: And presumably missing dates are simply excluded from the calculation, 
so the desired values are the averages of dates (1,2,3),(2,3,6), and (3,6,10)? (Although quite why we're continuing to bother with this question as it descends into chaos and confusion is beyond me)

Comment: @simon, really sorry it was mistake, the correct is 121.52

Comment: so you want the average of the last n rows, regardless of the date?

Comment: @simon, right date is immaterial, it should be of last n records from the date in focus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating a Moving Average MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121023/calculating-a-moving-average-mysql)

Comment: This is very easy to do in databases that support windowing functions. Unfortunately MySQL doesn't so people use various hacks. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16121640/134204) for a simple solution that uses a correlated subqyert and doesn't require joins.

Comment: For me the date is immaterial, it has to calculate for the n records

Comment: what is the primary key of your table? date?

Comment: @simon, there's no primary key

Comment: @Kris Your Primary Key is (date,product), and should be formally designated as such

Comment: @Strawberry, OK if alter the table to make date as primary key how could it help?. Thanks for the inputs

Comment: Date isn't the PRIMARY KEY. (date,product) is the PRIMARY KEY. It's a compound PRIMARY KEY. It's the difference between my query working and not working.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one idea. Note that a solution emplying variables will be orders of magnitude faster...

The sample result set omits averages comprising fewer than 3 values, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader... (although I've included a tiny clue)

```
SELECT a.date
     , a.product
     , a.value
     , ROUND(AVG(b.value),2) rolling
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) rank
         FROM my_table x
         JOIN my_table y
           ON y.product = x.product
          AND y.date <= x.date 
        GROUP
           BY x.product
            , x.date
     ) a
  LEFT 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) rank
         FROM my_table x
         JOIN my_table y
           ON y.product = x.product
          AND y.date <= x.date 
        GROUP
           BY x.product
            , x.date
     ) b
    ON b.product = a.product
   AND b.rank BETWEEN a.rank - 2 AND a.rank
 GROUP 
    BY a.date,a.product;
```

Comment: that's a great one. However I made slight tweak to make it perfect

Comment: Isn't the `value` picked randomly, since it is not a part of group by?

Comment: @KamilG. technically yes - but I'm grouping on a cardinality of 1, so it must always return the correct value. MySQL forgives this behaviour (although it's arguable whether it should). You can add value to the GROUP BY is you like, or if operating in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.date
    , a.product
    , a.value
    , round(avg(b.value),2) rolling
 from 
    (
    select x.*
        , count(*) rank 
        from my_table x 

        join my_table y 

        on y.product=x.product 

        and y.date >=x.date

        group 
        by x.product, 
        x.date order by x.date asc
    )
 a


 left
 join 

        (select x.*, 
        count(*) rank 
        from my_table x

        join my_table y

        on y.product = x.product

        and y.date >= x.date

        group 
        by x.product
        , x.date order by x.date asc
    )
    b

    on b.product =a.product 

    and a.rank between b.rank -2 and b.rank

 group 
    by a.date, a.product order by a.date desc;
```