# How do I calculate the hourly 4 week moving average by weekday?

Tags: mysql

Given a table with a datetime column, I want to get the 4 week moving average number of entries per hour with the day of week for each result.

So for instance, between Oct 1st and Oct 13th, I'd like to get back a result that shows the 4 week rolling average for number of rows grouped by hour and dayofweek.

What I have so far gets me the 4 week hourly totals, but not rolling totals:

```
SELECT 
   DAYOFWEEK(start_time) as DOW, 
   date_format( start_time, '%H' ) as 'HOUR',
   count( * ) as 'count' 
FROM mytable 
WHERE start_time >='2017-08-01' and start_time <= '2017-08-29' 
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(start_time),date_format( start_time, '%H' )
```

Comment: be aware that `between` is not good for date/time ranges. your where clause is the equivalent of this: `start_time >= '2017-08-01 00:00:00' and start_time <= '2017-08-29 00:00:00'` (not sure if you wanted the whole day of Aug 29 or not) instead use `start_time >= '2017-08-01 00:00:00' and start_time < '2017-08-30 00:00:00'` (which gives you all of Aug 29 but nothing from Aug 30)

Comment: sorry the extra `00:00:00's` are not needed. Just for explanation. Have a look at ths frmer question on the same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121023/calculating-a-moving-average-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partially tested approach.

It uses date parameters to ensure consistency of the where clauses. Other parameters are also used to control the hourly bucket (I used 3 in limited testing), and the number of weeks (I used 0 in testing as I had a very small set of rows).

The first subquery is used to produce "ranges" which when joined to the source rows will place those rows into each "rolling n hourly range". Those ranges are defined by using a date_format output YYYYMMDDHH which are strings, and then the data is also forced to this same string format for joining,  so if being used on a large table this may cause performance issues (yes, not sargable, I don't like it either).

This solution may be seen working [here at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b05841/1)

*Schema Setup*:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `start_time` datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO MyTable
    (`start_time`)
VALUES
    ('2017-08-01 00:01:00'),
    ('2017-08-01 00:15:00'),
    ('2017-08-01 00:29:00'),

    ## more here, 3 rows per hour over a narrow date range

    ('2017-08-03 08:01:00'),
    ('2017-08-03 08:15:00'),
    ('2017-08-03 08:29:00')
;
```

**Query**

```
set @start_time := '2017-08-02';
set @num_hrs    := 4; -- controls length of rolling period e.g. 4 hours each
set @num_weeks  := 4; -- controls the date date

set @end_time   := date_add(@start_time, INTERVAL ((7 * @num_weeks)+1) DAY);

SELECT
       DOW
     , hour_of_day 
     , COUNT(*) period_count
     , (COUNT(*) * 1.0) / @num_hrs rolling_av
FROM (
    ## build a set of ranges in YYYYMMDDHH format differing by the wanted number of hours
    SELECT 
          id
       ,  DATE_FORMAT(date_add(start_time, INTERVAL (@num_hrs*-1) HOUR), '%Y%m%d%H') as range_start
       ,  DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y%m%d%H') as range_end
    FROM mytable
    WHERE start_time >= @start_time and start_time < @end_time
    ) R
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
           start_time
         , DAYOFWEEK(start_time) as DOW 
         , date_format(start_time, '%H' ) as hour_of_day
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE start_time >= @start_time and start_time < @end_time
    ) T ON DATE_FORMAT(T.start_time, '%Y%m%d%H') >= R.range_start
                    AND DATE_FORMAT(T.start_time, '%Y%m%d%H') <= R.range_end
GROUP BY 
       DOW, hour_of_day
ORDER BY 
       DOW, hour_of_day
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b05841/1/4)**:

```
| DOW | hour_of_day | period_count | rolling_av |
|-----|-------------|--------------|------------|
|   4 |          00 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          01 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          02 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          03 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          04 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          05 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          06 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          07 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          08 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          09 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          10 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          11 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          12 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          13 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          14 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          15 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          16 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          17 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          18 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          19 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          20 |           36 |         12 |
|   4 |          21 |           27 |          9 |
|   4 |          22 |           18 |          6 |
|   4 |          23 |            9 |          3 |
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! This is really helpful already. What I'm really looking for is to just provide a date range and get back the results more or less as you have described.

Additionally, I'm a little confused about what is happening here with the 3hr bucket.

Comment: I created just 3 rows per hour for a couple of days in my sample data so that I wouldn't exceed sqlfidle's small data allowance. Due to setting the num_hrs to 3 then allowed me to get predictable results. All you have to do is `set @num_hrs    := 4; set @num_weeks  := 4;` and it should be god to go. You will need to test it to your satisfaction of course.

Comment: Finally, I am working with a largish database around 300,000 entries, with a few thousand entries added daily.

Could you explain why setting hours to 4 works? What is actually happening there with the hour setting?

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with using the AVG keyword in the FROM clause in the first sub-query.

Comment: I cannot tell you how much I appreciate your help here.

So can @end_time could be a distinct date?

The comments you added are very helpful, but how does

Comment: 1. AVG should not be in the code, it isn't needed (was a copy/paste error I suspect)  2. I may have misread the question. What the code does is deducts @num_hrs from each hour over to give you the "moving average" per hour. If you really wanted 4 week moving averages PER HOUR then the number of hours would be (4*7*24)

Comment: "So end time could be a distinct date?" what end time? all you need are the parameters provided. (start date +  a number of weeks) = date range

Comment: set @end_time   := date_add(@start_time, INTERVAL ((7 * @num_weeks)+1) DAY)

That could be replaced with '2017-08-20'?

I am looking for the 4 week average of entries, by day, by hour. In the process I would like to catch the day of the week.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156790/discussion-between-joomsavvy-and-used-by-already).

Comment: No. That calculates the end of the date range. Trace the query for where @end_time is positioned. it is the there where clauses, that's all it does. it is `@num_hrs` that you need to alter, and to get 4 weeks then (4*7*24)  pleas consider that you asked for these averages PER HOUR, so the precision has to be BY HOUR