# Is there a mysql function to get average of last three days timeduration from data available in form of SCHEMA(date, time)

Tags: mysql

I am querying on a table which have two columns(date, timeduration) timeduration is in long format. I would like to generate result where its like(date, timeduration) and this timeduration should be average of last three days timeduration.

date          | timeduration
 01-01-2019          50
 02-01-2019          75
 03-01-2019          100
 04-01-2019          125

Its result should be

```
    date         |  timeduration
     01-01-2019          50           i.e (50)/1
     02-01-2019          62.5         i.e (50+75)/2
     03-01-2019          75           i.e (50+75+100)/3
     04-01-2019          100          i.e (75+100+125)/3
```

I have tried assigning rownumbers and accessing last three days via rownumbers.

It should be in mysql, if there is any way to achieve this please suggest me one

```
    date         |  timeduration
   01-01-2019          50           explanation (50)/1
   02-01-2019          62.5         explanation (50+75)/2
   03-01-2019          75           explanation (50+75+100)/3
   04-01-2019          100          explanation (75+100+125)/3
```

Comment: See [Calculating a Moving Average MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16121023). (The first answer only does this for one day, but the others do it for more). If you are on MySQL 8, you can also use window functions.