# How to write an SQL query to calculate the average for three consecutive values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
userID    time    NoOfVisits
  1       2014       50
  2       2015       60
  3       2016       70
  4       2017       80
  5       2018       90
  6       2019       100
```

I need to write a sql query which will print time and average of past 3 years NoOfVisits for a particular site.

output should be as

```
userID    time    NoOfVisits   
  1       2014    50.0000
  2       2015    55.0000
  3       2016    60.0000
  4       2017    70.0000
  5       2018    80.0000
  6       2019    90.0000
```

Explanation :

For user Id 6 (80+90+100)/3=90.0000

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: which version of MySQL are you using? how should you handle a missing year in between? please add these details to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating a Moving Average MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121023/calculating-a-moving-average-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative average, available in MySQL 8+:

```
select t.*,
       avg(visits) over (order by time rows between 2 preceding and current row) as avg_visits_3
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no gaps between the years (like your sample data), you can self join the table and `group by userid, time` to get the average:

```
select
  t.userid, t.time, avg(tt.noofvisits) NoOfVisits
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on tt.time between t.time - 2 and t.time
group by t.userid, t.time
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b1NVesdGuwfP1k4Fy8J1yu/0).
Results:

```
| userid | time | NoOfVisits |
| ------ | ---- | ---------- |
| 1      | 2014 | 50         |
| 2      | 2015 | 55         |
| 3      | 2016 | 60         |
| 4      | 2017 | 70         |
| 5      | 2018 | 80         |
| 6      | 2019 | 90         |
```