# MySQL - Calculating a daily 7 day moving sum with DATETIME dates and gaps

Tags: mysql

Ultimately trying to get a rolling daily sum of the quantity column (where the 'daily sum' is a sum of the last 7 days), even if there is no data for that date range. Something like this:

[image]

I have already found and attempted the suggestions below without much success. I think my problem arises from the fact that I have my dates stored as datetime and there can be days which have no entries for them. Very new to SQL in general so sorry if I misuse any terminology.

In [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6309c/30) I tried [the technique here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121023/calculating-a-moving-average-mysql) where it looks like its using a correlated subquery to calculate  the sum, but it doesn't really work for some reason, it just keeps summing the prior rows.

```
SELECT DATE(purchase_date), SUM(quantity),
   (SELECT SUM(quantity) 
   FROM all_orders as all_orders_past 
   WHERE datediff(all_orders_past.purchase_date, all_orders.purchase_date) <= 7
   ) as mvgSum
FROM all_orders
GROUP BY DATE(purchase_date)
ORDER BY DATE(purchase_date) DESC
```

In [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6309c/31) I tried this [technique here](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/rolling-average) which uses self-joins and should handle date gaps but I'm seeing some really odd results where the 7 day sum is 1 when it should definitely be more.

```
SELECT DATE(all_orders.purchase_date), SUM(all_orders.quantity), SUM(all_orders_past.quantity)
FROM all_orders
JOIN all_orders as all_orders_past 
  on all_orders_past.purchase_date between all_orders.purchase_date - 6 and all_orders.purchase_date
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY DATE(all_orders.purchase_date) DESC;
```

Seems like a combination of the two is needed but I'm not sure what that would even look like.

Dataset for ease of reference:

```
create table all_orders (
    id INT,
    purchase_date DATETIME,
    quantity VARCHAR(1),
    item_status VARCHAR(9),
    asin VARCHAR(10)
);
insert into all_orders (id, purchase_date, quantity, item_status, asin) values 
    (1, '2018-11-17 15:17:58', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (2, '2018-11-16 18:16:48', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (3, '2018-11-21 02:13:01', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (4, '2018-11-08 03:33:16', 3, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (5, '2018-11-17 15:39:35', 1, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (6, '2018-11-07 13:51:54', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (7, '2018-11-20 02:53:52', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (8, '2018-11-12 20:46:48', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (9, '2018-11-11 07:00:45', 3, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (10, '2018-11-09 18:19:24', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (11, '2018-11-09 03:35:05', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (12, '2018-11-05 17:02:46', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (13, '2018-11-15 18:37:25', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (14, '2018-11-10 22:32:01', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (15, '2018-11-21 04:48:22', 3, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (16, '2018-11-08 10:39:01', 2, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (17, '2018-11-14 13:23:56', 3, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (18, '2018-11-12 01:19:53', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (19, '2018-11-06 02:55:06', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (20, '2018-11-18 22:07:01', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (21, '2018-11-09 12:31:32', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (22, '2018-11-17 01:51:43', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (23, '2018-11-10 23:40:26', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (24, '2018-11-18 18:05:37', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (25, '2018-11-07 10:40:41', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (26, '2018-11-12 20:56:32', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (27, '2018-11-07 16:09:02', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (28, '2018-11-13 17:28:32', 1, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (29, '2018-11-12 23:14:54', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (30, '2018-11-17 06:47:50', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (31, '2018-11-11 14:12:13', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (32, '2018-11-12 23:42:08', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (33, '2018-11-13 01:01:27', 3, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (34, '2018-11-13 17:02:58', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (35, '2018-11-13 18:44:41', 1, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (36, '2018-11-04 07:04:12', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (37, '2018-11-04 04:56:10', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (38, '2018-11-13 14:55:40', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (39, '2018-11-09 00:54:42', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (40, '2018-11-21 03:11:28', 3, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (41, '2018-11-14 08:19:59', 3, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (42, '2018-11-04 01:04:29', 3, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (43, '2018-11-21 22:49:16', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (44, '2018-11-09 17:29:48', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (45, '2018-11-08 09:05:29', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (46, '2018-11-20 23:47:21', 1, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (47, '2018-11-19 14:16:29', 3, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (48, '2018-11-14 13:05:33', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (49, '2018-11-21 20:41:09', 2, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (50, '2018-11-11 18:41:56', 3, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (51, '2018-11-11 05:34:07', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (52, '2018-11-10 06:16:35', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (53, '2018-11-09 01:10:37', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (54, '2018-11-07 18:01:34', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (55, '2018-11-18 13:33:35', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (56, '2018-11-12 06:25:56', 1, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (57, '2018-11-15 14:13:01', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (58, '2018-11-04 02:32:48', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (59, '2018-11-09 12:48:53', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (60, '2018-11-11 02:40:51', 1, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (61, '2018-11-14 15:01:13', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (62, '2018-11-12 06:29:30', 2, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (63, '2018-11-04 05:53:07', 2, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (64, '2018-11-18 21:33:31', 1, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (65, '2018-11-16 06:57:31', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (66, '2018-11-20 11:59:19', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (67, '2018-11-12 00:43:23', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (68, '2018-11-12 21:58:53', 1, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (69, '2018-11-15 18:29:35', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (70, '2018-11-15 09:10:53', 3, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (71, '2018-11-20 07:01:51', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (72, '2018-11-06 12:52:26', 1, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (73, '2018-11-19 10:49:55', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (74, '2018-11-20 21:26:19', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (75, '2018-11-10 07:35:08', 2, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (76, '2018-11-09 01:32:33', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (77, '2018-11-17 07:08:10', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (78, '2018-11-07 23:51:43', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (79, '2018-11-09 20:28:27', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (80, '2018-11-06 04:01:45', 3, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (81, '2018-11-15 02:33:34', 2, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (82, '2018-11-15 03:55:42', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (83, '2018-11-21 23:10:38', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWABC'),
     (84, '2018-11-15 18:11:32', 2, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (85, '2018-11-12 09:41:02', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (86, '2018-11-13 12:34:34', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (87, '2018-11-07 06:10:33', 1, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (88, '2018-11-11 02:26:23', 1, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (89, '2018-11-13 04:01:40', 3, 'Shipped', 'B072BPWXPG'),
     (90, '2018-11-17 17:27:18', 3, 'Cancelled', 'B072BPWXPG');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following:

```
SELECT a.purchase_date, a.quantity, sum(p.quantity) as 'past_quantity'
FROM (
  SELECT DATE(purchase_date) as purchase_date , sum(quantity) as quantity
  FROM all_orders
  GROUP BY 1
  UNION
  SELECT cdate, 0
  FROM calendar_dates
  WHERE cdate NOT IN (
    SELECT DATE(purchase_date)
    FROM all_orders
  ) AND cdate between (SELECT MIN(purchase_date) FROM all_orders)
    AND (SELECT MAX(purchase_date) FROM all_orders)
) AS a
  JOIN all_orders p on DATE(p.purchase_date) between 
    DATE_ADD(DATE(a.purchase_date), INTERVAL -6 day) and DATE(a.purchase_date)
WHERE a.purchase_date between '2018-11-10' and '2018-11-12'
GROUP BY a.purchase_date, a.quantity
```

So, what you do is first get the sums of individual dates (one row/date) and then join it to get the sum of past days.

Easiest way (and a way to get best performance) for the missing dates is to create a calendar table with all dates (all by your definition and include that in the query.

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1961c5/2)

Comment: This is very close to what I am trying to do, thanks. The only thing is that it doesn't seem to handle is gaps in data. For example if I remove the entries for '2018-11-04' leaving that date empty there will be no past_quantity sum for that date.

Comment: Then you have to define the date range from which you wish to get the numbers from. What defines the date range or is it just from min(date) to max(date).

Comment: If it was just min(date) to max(date) what would it look like, or could you just point me in the right direction?

Comment: Added sample use of a calendar table. You could do it within the query as well, but it would complicate things and would lead to worse performance. Hence the calendar table.

Comment: This worked out perfect by the way, but perfomance is a bit slow, taking 2 seconds across ~200000 records, is this to be expected?

Comment: You are basically calculating all data in the table as you do not have limitation for the days. If you have proper indexes and limit the date range you wish to receive, the performance will be better.

Comment: One more question if you have the time, how do I further filter the results to a certain date range, say `BETWEEN DATE("2019-01-01") AND DATE("2019-10-15")`. I've tried to edit the above code in multiple ways and always seem to get the results going back to 2017 or I lose the ability to have days with 0 values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need all those joins. If you're selecting based on a given date, you could do this:

```
set @myDate = '2018-11-21';

select date(purchase_date) as date, sum(if(date(purchase_date) = @myDate, quantity, 0)) as today, sum(quantity) as last_week
from all_orders
where date(purchase_date) between timestampadd(DAY, -6, @myDate) and @myDate;
```

You want only the last 7 days (based on your date) fetched, and then the sum of today (your date) and the sum of the whole period. For a given day, you can combine `sum` and `if`. For the whole period you can just sum.

Comment: OP wants outputs for each of the last 7 days, _even if there is no data for those days_. First paragraph in the question: _...in the last 7 days, even if there is no data for that date range._

Comment: @Martin the word "each" is absent in the question. He wants the sum for the entire range

Comment: @Aryton - _a daily sum_

Comment: If that was the case the queries he attempted would have more than just 3 columns. If he wants a sum for each of the seven days he has to clarify it

Comment: @Ayrton Updated my question to: 'trying to get a rolling daily sum of the quantity column (where the 'daily sum' is a sum of the last 7 days)'

Comment: @ScrapeHeap so you actually just want a sum of the entire range? In that case, try what I did in my answer. If you're being literal about the **last seven days** part, just assign the value of today's date to `@myDate`

Answer (score 0):

I've interpreted your question to mean that you want to retrieve a row *per day* for the last seven days showing your data *even when that day has no existing rows*.

What you are looking for is a sequence, but MySQL does not currently have native support for them.

There are a few differing solutions for this, but in your case a simple `UNION` statement can get a list of rows for the last 7 days:

```
SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL DayOffset DAY
  FROM (
       SELECT 0 DayOffset UNION ALL SELECT -1 UNION ALL SELECT -2 UNION ALL SELECT -3 UNION ALL SELECT -4 UNION ALL SELECT -5 UNION ALL SELECT -6
       ) a
```

This will output a list of dates for the last 7 days (inclusive of today):

```
2019-11-04
2019-11-03
2019-11-02
2019-11-01
2019-10-31
2019-10-30
2019-10-29
```

Now in order to get your results, you can just `JOIN` to this from your query.  The following code is untested but will steer you in the right direction:

```
SELECT DATE(purchase_date),
       SUM(quantity)
  FROM all_orders ao
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL DayOffset DAY AS DateOffset
                  FROM (
                       SELECT 0 DayOffset UNION ALL SELECT -1 UNION ALL SELECT -2 UNION ALL SELECT -3 UNION ALL SELECT -4 UNION ALL SELECT -5 UNION ALL SELECT -6
                       ) a
                ) a ON a.DateOffset = ao.DATE(purchase_date)
  GROUP BY DATE(purchase_date)
  ORDER BY DATE(purchase_date) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
SELECT DATE(purchase_date) date_orig, SUM(quantity),
   (SELECT SUM(quantity) 
   FROM all_orders as all_orders_past 
   WHERE all_orders_past.purchase_date between date_orig - interval 6 day
    and date_orig +interval 1 day
   ) as mvgSum
FROM all_orders
GROUP BY date_orig
ORDER BY date_orig DESC
```

[image: Test:]