# Calculating moving average for different values in a column MySQL

Tags: mysql, moving-average

I have a dataset like this:

```
team   date        score
A      2011-05-01    50
A      2011-05-02    54
A      2011-05-03    51
A      2011-05-04    49
A      2011-05-05    59
B      2011-05-03    30
B      2011-05-04    35
B      2011-05-05    39
B      2011-05-06    47
B      2011-05-07    50
```

I want to add another column called `MA3` where I can calculate the moving average of scores for the last 3 days. The point that made it tricky is to calculate the MA for each team. The end result should be like this:

```
team   date         score   MA3
A      2011-05-01    50    null
A      2011-05-02    54    null
A      2011-05-03    51    null
A      2011-05-04    49    51.66
A      2011-05-05    59    51.33
B      2011-05-03    30    null
B      2011-05-04    35    null
B      2011-05-05    39    null
B      2011-05-06    47    34.66
B      2011-05-07    50    40.33
```

If that would be a single team, I would go on and do:

```
SELECT team, 
       year,
       AVG(score) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC ROWS 3 PRECEDING) AS MA3
FROM   table
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating a Moving Average MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121023/calculating-a-moving-average-mysql)

Comment: No, it doesn't  because here I am trying to do the calculation for different values in a column

Comment: @P.Salmon: [I've added an answer there too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61709031/521799). Interestingly, there was no answer for MySQL 8 and window functions in that question yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `PARTITION BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT team, 
       date,
       AVG(score) OVER (
         PARTITION BY team
         ORDER BY date ASC ROWS 3 PRECEDING
       ) AS MA3
FROM   table
```

Note that there will always be an average calculation, regardless of the window size. If you want the average to be `null` if your window size is smaller than 3, you could do it like this:

```sql
SELECT team, 
       date,
       CASE 
         WHEN count(*) OVER w <= 3 THEN null 
         ELSE AVG(score) OVER w
       END AS MA3
FROM   table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY date ASC ROWS 3 PRECEDING)
```

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/orSBuwcTwz138xUDSv66u1/0)

#### Side note

Your next question might be about [logical windowing](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/10/31/a-little-known-sql-feature-use-logical-windowing-to-aggregate-sliding-ranges/), because often, you don't actually want to calculate the average over 3 rows, but over some interval, 
like e.g. 3 days. Luckily, MySQL implements this. You could then write:

```sql
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY date ASC RANGE INTERVAL 3 DAY PRECEDING)
```

Comment: Actually I will use the range interval option. That will provide a better solution here and very helpful article!